# Saving Drag and Drop position primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Good day. I have here a drag-and-drop implementation using primefaces. This is for the draggables.

```
<p:dataGrid id="availableComputers" value="#{coltsysLab.computer}" var="computer" columns="3" emptyMessage="No Computers Added Yet">   
<p:column>  

    <p:graphicImage id="computer" value="http://localhost:8080/COLTSysResources/resources/images/#{computer.pic}" styleClass="computerImage" rendered="#{computer.status=='AVAILABLE'}"/>  

    <p:draggable for="computer" revert="true" scope="#{computer.status}" stack=".computerImage"/>

    <p:contextMenu for="computer">
        <p:menuitem value="Add Information" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" onclick="addInfoDlg.show();" action="#{coltsysLab.passComputerId(computer)}"/>
        <p:menuitem process="@this" value="Computer Information" icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="viewInfoDlg.show()" action="#{coltsysLab.passComputerId(computer)}"/>
    </p:contextMenu>

</p:column>
```

This is for the droppable slots.

```
<p:dataGrid id="slots" value="#{coltsysLab.op}" var="com1" columns="#{coltsysLab.column}" >  
<p:outputPanel id="drop" styleClass="slot">
    <p:droppable for="drop" datasource=":organizeForm:availableComputers" tolerance="fit" scope="AVAILABLE">
        <p:ajax process="slots" listener="#{coltsysLab.onDrop}" update=":organizeForm:growl :organizeForm:selectedComputers"/>
    </p:droppable>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I was able to get the dragId and dropId through the DragDropEvent on the backing bean. But how will I be able to save the position of each slot containing a draggable? I want to save it to the database so that when I open the page, it'll show the saved positions of each draggable.

--

I added a code from kolossus' suggestion, I want to get the position of the dragged object, but here, it outputs `null`.

```
String dropId = event.getDropId();
UIComponent theContainer = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":organizeForm:slots"); 
UIComponent theComponent = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":organizeForm:availableComputers:computer");
List<UIComponent> childComponents = theContainer.getChildren();

    for (UIComponent child : childComponents) {

        System.out.println(child.getClientId());

        if (dropId.equals(child.getClientId())) {

            GraphicImage gImage = (GraphicImage) theComponent;
            String currentPosition = gImage.getStyle();
            System.out.println(currentPosition);
        }
    }
```

When I use inspect element of a browser, I can see it's style, how will I be able to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

The position of the elements of a page is represented by the `style` attribute. So in your case, you simply need to get the current value of the dropped component. For that, you need to retrieve the component in the view by its clientId. Unfortunately, JSF doesn't provide an easy way to get this information (it's pretty easy to get a component by its `id` though); I know only of a brute force approach:

```
String dropId = dde.getDropId();  //get the currently dropped component
UIComponent theContainer =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("slots"); //you need a reference to the drop container
List<UIComponent> childComponents =  theContainer.getChildren(); //all dropped components are children of the datagrid

for(UIComponent child: childComponents){
   if(dropId.equals(child.getClientId()));{
      GraphicImage gImage = (GraphicImage) theComponent;
      String currentPosition = gImage.getStyle();
   }
}
```

Comment: i guess theComponent is this? `UIComponent theComponent = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("availableComputers:computer");` but it returns null on getStyle

Comment: @Francis - You probably should include the `slots` component in the `process` attritbute of the drop ajax listener. If you inspect the element source of the page you're viewing, you'll notice that the style attribute is updated, but it's happening on the client side only; JSF still needs to be informed of the change in style

Comment: i added `process="slots"` but still null